# SSIS - Script task to create xlsx file (Export data from sql database to new excel file)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have data flow task, which import data from sql server to excel. Currently it requires to have excel templated in place, meaning that I have xlsx file with column names without data in my network location. If I run the package the excel will be filled with data.

What is needed: If I run ssis package I need new xlsx file to be created every time if package is executed. So I need to just create xlsx file with define columns every time and the xlsx file name should include date.

I imagine that I have to set up script task before data flow task, which just creates xlsx file. I am not very familiar with C#, I hope that someone could share the code what to use to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, you could create a folder and place a Template excel file with predefined format and no data.

Every time the process runs, it must:

- Copy the file using File System task to the destination location
- Use Data flow task to populate the data into the file in the Destination location
- Rename the file in the Destination location as required

Comment: Tried this approach as well. I have one issue with it, if I copy file from temp folder to main folder and now would like to insert data into this excel, it fails saying that excel file is missing. My current control flow is following: File System Task (copy file from temp folder to main folder) > Data Flow Task (insert data into excel, what was copied in previous step) > File System Task (rename file name). If I execute those task separately, it work, bur if I run package it will not.

Comment: What is the error that you get? If it is validation error, you can set Delay Validation. May be an issue with the connection string. It is best to build the connection string in a variable and assign it to the connection string. All tasks, connection strings, user variables have "Properties" which can be altered during package run time through "Expression".

Comment: The message itself is: "
Error at Data Flow Task 1 [Excel Destination [443]]: Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database."
I assume that the issue is because it is checking is the file exists, what is set in excel destination before execution, but the file is copied to this location in first File System Task. I also tried to set file path in variable, but same error.

Comment: The Sheet name of the excel file being copied and the Sheet name in the Source editor of the Data Flow Task must be the same. Also, close all excel files while running the package. The property Delay Validation set to TRUE will ensure that the Package not to validate the file existence or connection strings..

Comment: Since Excel is used, the Run64BitRuntime Project Property must be set to False.

Comment: Thanks, it was related to delay validation setting, now it works (Y)